# Delphi 2009 Upgrade Question

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, upgrade, delphi-5

i bought yesterday an upgrade to Delphi 2009 Pro. Now i have the problem that i have a version of Delphi 5 Enterprise, but it's registered, but the account has been lost.

Is there a way to get the Delphi 5 version to be moved to my account, so that i can register the Delphi 2009 Pro.

Otherwise i also got a Delphi 3 Pro laying around here, which also should be enough for upgrading, but how can i get this registered?

My other Delphi's are Delphi 1, Delphi 2 Developer and Delphi 3 Standard as well as some Personal Versions.

Has anybody a good idea what i should be doing now? The best would be to move the Enterprise Delphi to my current account.

Cheers, murphy

Comment: I don't understand. Is Delphi 2009 refusing to let you install it? Is it refusing to let you register it?

Comment: Is it actually just an upgrade? You probably can install it without any problems, if it were the case that a Borland/Embarcadero required the employee who registered Delphi 3 to register Delphi 2010, that seems like it'd be a lot of work.   I agree that you should have the satisfaction of seeing all your registered Delphi versions when you log into EDN though, hope things work out, I'd definitely contact them, they are very friendly folks.

Comment: I bought it private from a licensed owner. The license must be moved over to my account, but there is no Delphi 5 or Delphi 3 in it. And no, i haven't it installed yet. I was thinking in advance :)

Comment: Murphy, I don't think you have any actual problem. Please try it out, and then come back if you really encounter any issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to contact [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/). If you have a registered version they must have records of that. It will be helpful if you know the email address that was used to register the account.

Comment: Not really. The email adress is also lost. I have the CD with the Key, so i can prove it with a picture.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 2009 upgrade is available to owners of any earlier version of Delphi, so you should be able to upgrade from Delphi 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably making a mountain out of a molehill.  If you haven't tried to install it yet then I would cross that bridge when you come to it.  I don't believe having your Delphi 5 or 3 install associated with your account will make any difference.  I am pretty sure Delphi 5 and earlier didn't have an activation, so there probably isn't anything to transfer.

More likely you will have trouble if the person you purchased it from used up the activations for 2009.  Additionally, last I checked, they only support purchasing Delphi from a licensed reseller, which it sounds like wasn't the case.

I hope it works out for you though.  Delphi 2009 is a great release and well worth the upgrade!

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 5 doesn’t require online activation. The key should be enough to get it properly installed.